# Do we have any callbacks available for talkback(Accessibility) android

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

My scenario is i have been using the accessibility feature for some of the views in my application and wanted to check do we have any callback which will notify a view once the talkback operation is either completed or is in-progress something similar to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "talkback operation"?

Comment: Actually, i have defined the content description for the textviews in my application and enabled the talk back in settings unders the accessibility section. Android starts reading the content description of the textview as the user interacts with the view. Now, my question here is,
is it possible for us to get notified of the TalkBack completion(android completed reading the content description of the view) event?
Thank you.

Comment: No.  thirteen ch....  Instead of asking about a specific bit of functionality, try describing the behavior you want.  There may be a similar API available to get the behaviour you're looking for.  But the specific thing you describe is not possible. (I suppose maybe some super hacky things involving looking at audio output).  But, these would be easily broken by background audio.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To elaborate my question in detail, I am developing an application which has a functionality to logout of the application if the user is inactive or idle for some time(lets say 30 seconds). And i have a textview in one of my screen with the content description defined for the talkback and the problem that i have been facing here is that if the content description of a textview is bigger, android talkback service is taking more than 30 seconds to read it completely and by the time application is getting signed off because of my other condition(30 seconds idle).

Comment: I am looking for same solution, signout functionality when accessibility on. Please post if you find any solution for this?